# Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist:

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I have created a input directory and put sample file in it.I have created an output directory also.but at the time of mapreduce program execution i got the below error.Here is my command to execute mapreduce

```
bin/hdfs dfs -mkdir /input
bin/hdfs dfs -put /home/biswajit/sample.txt /input/
bin/hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.9.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/units.jar com.hadoop.ProcessUnits /input/sample.txt /output
```

Error is

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: **hdfs://localhost:54310/home/biswajit/input/sample.txt**
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:294)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeOldSplits(JobSubmitter.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:333)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:202)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1570)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1567)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1886)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1567)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:576)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:571)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1886)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:571)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:562)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:871)
    at com.hadoop.ProcessUnits.main(ProcessUnits.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:239)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:153)
```

Comment: Please add code and sample input detail.

Comment: did u see my error?its not a coding problem

Comment: You have put the file into some `/input/` folder and passing the path `$HADOOP_HOME/input` as input folder. Is the input folder created at the location referred by `$HADOOP_HOME`?

Comment: yes the folder is in $HADOOP_HOME/input.If i create /input folder in hadoop what is the default location?

Comment: It depends on the hadoop distribution. e.g. `mapr` distribution does not have **by default** `$HADOOP_HOME` concept to put the file on HDFS. Neither its path is represented in `hdfs://..` url scheme in a mapreduce program.

Comment: my mistake the command is like - bin/hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.9.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/units.jar com.hadoop.ProcessUnits /input/sample.txt /output

Comment: Can you successfully do `hdfs dfs -ls /input/sample.txt`?

Comment: yes i can hdfs dfs -ls /input/sample.txt

Answer (score 0):

`$HADOOP_HOME/input` doesn't exist on HDFS.

`$HADOOP_HOME` is a bash variable on your **local** filesystem.

You only created a directory for `/input`, so you can either `mkdir` the full path with the variable, if you want that command to run as-is, or you need to remove the variable when running the JAR file

As long as `hdfs dfs -ls /input/*` shows some files, then that command looks fine otherwise, but I'm not sure what that Java class is actually expecting as input

Note: there is a difference between

```
 hdfs://localhost:54310/home/biswajit/input
```

And

```
hdfs://localhost:54310/input
```

More specifically, HDFS doesn't have `/home` folders, so it looks like you're either not running pseudo distributed cluster, or you made that directory yourself.